# Where does /etc/services come from?

Tags: networking, services

I am thinking about the evolution of computer networks, and I am looking at `/etc/services`.  There is a lot of information in there, a lot of ports I don't recognize.

I went to [IANA Service Name and Transport Protocol Port Number Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml?&page=2) ([IANA is the Internet Assigned Numbers Authority](https://www.iana.org/)), and that makes me even more confused.  So, for example, a lot of the assigned ports are tied to services with RFCs.  Port 80, HTTP, is not one of those.  The same is true with port 443.  Yet these two ports are arguably the most important on the internet.

In the grand scheme of things, this really isn't an important question.  In general, people of all kinds think of services, then implementations, then protocols, and then ports.  I am not familiar with any new network protocols that are not implemented using either HTTP or HTTPS or both.  That's not to say that there aren't, but rather that such a service getting implemented on its own port, would have to have a good reason for getting its own port.  So, for example, elasticsearch connects to port 9200 by default, and kibana connects to port 5601 by default.  Neither of those numbers are in `/etc/services`.  Why not?

Again, please don't get me wrong.  I have elasticsearch working quite nicely and I am well on my way to getting kibana working as soon as I get my reverse proxy going.  I'm just curious where `/etc/services` comes from, why there are some things in there that make no sense to me, and why there are some things missing.

Thank you

Comment: I can't see how it is related to Ubuntu.

Comment: you have lot of time since you are curious about these ......

Comment: Technically, I am asking in the wrong place.  I should be asking in a debian forum.
In the file, it says: "...or needed by a debian package..."
Later, there are comments about ports 2111/tcp and 2121/tcp.  Finally, there is a comment: # Services added for the Debian GNU/Linux distribution.  That's why I'm curious about /etc/services being distribution specific.  IMHO, /etc/services should be the same across all distros and eco-systems.